# IE8 crash when open two tabs showing the same webpage that loads activex control

Tags: tabs, internet-explorer-8, crash, controls, activex

I have develop an activex control used in IE webpage. If i just open one page that need to load my 
activex control in IE 8, it works fine. But when i open two or more pages that need to load my control in tabs in IE8,
IE8 will crash when I open new tabs.

I notice that, when i open two tabs, these two tabs run in the same process. And there are many global variables in my activex
control, when two controls run in the same process, the global control conflict which lead to the crash of IE8.
If i set TabProcGrowth registry key to a value larger than 1, make every IE8 tab works in one independent process, 
everything goes well. But this is not what I want, is there any other way to solve this kind of problem?

As the ActiveX control i developed uses other libs, it’s impossible for me to kill all the global variables.
The ideal solution is that, there is a setting item in windows system or IE8. By this setting i can make ie8 open these webpages
that using my control in one independent process, but for other webpage, it works as normal.
But i don't know where to do this kind of setting.

As to IE11, when i open two tabs, two plugins also work in the same process, but IE11 doesn't crash！

Answer (score 0):

IE11 runs each tab as a separate process. IE8 does not. This means that global variables will be shared between tabs in IE8 but in IE11 each tab has its own process and it's own set of global variables.

This is a feature that was added in IE11 specifically to help with stability; ie if a tab does crash, it won't take down the whole browser.

IE8 doesn't have this feature, and it certainly won't get added now as MS are not supporting it any more.

So in short, I think you're pretty much stuck; I don't think there's any solution to offer apart from either getting your users to upgrade to IE11 or rewriting your control to get rid of the globals.